# Format number in JavaScript with given DecimalFormat pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

We need help formatting numbers in JavaScript.

Currently, we present a table to the user and add (sum) the numbers in its columns. This is done on the client side so we have to use JavaScript, but there are two problems.  First, Numeral.js handles extra zeros in a way that we don’t like (#.## 3 is rendered as 3.00 instead of 3). Second, we would like to be able to control formatting in exactly the same manner as Java’s DecimalFormat class, i.e., we would like to be able to use all of the DecimalFormat formatting options in JavaScript.

How can we support all of the DecimalFormat formatting options in JavaScript?

Comment: I have no idea how could this question attract opinionated answers as spam. The question is "How can I format a number in JavaScript using DecimalFormat's pattern from Java?", mentions steps done so far (looking for libraries) and why they didn't solve the problem. And even if OP asked for a library, the requirements are specific enough, that there won't be too many contenders. StackOverflow is read-only these days...